# Ударение в имени великомученика Пантелеймона Целителя

Tags: фонетика

Речь о святом великомученике Пантелеймоне Целителе. Как правильно ставить ударение в имени: ПантелЕймой или ПантелеймОн? Мне попадалось и так, и так, а в молитвослове ударение не стоит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как обычное имя - ПантелЕй, но ПантелеймОн.

Но целитель - ПантелеИмон, именно в такой форме имя было впервые заимствовано из греческого, в церковной лексике эта форма сохраняется. В быту, думаю, форма ПантелеймОн-целитель вполне допустима.

19.03.2012
Вынужден дополнить. 
По-прежнему считаю, что вне сугубо церковного контекста употребление формы "Пантелеймон-целитель" более чем допустимо. Искусственное насаждение якобы греческой формы (на самом деле - искусственной, ибо в древнерусском не было дифтонга "ей") под предлогом сохранения русскости выглядит весьма неуклюже. 
Этак мы дойдем до "Иоана-купалы" и "святаго Володимера".

Answer (score 2):

Во всех ответах одна и та же ошибка. Неправильное прочтение имени святого великомученика и целителя ПантелеИмона. В его имени нет буквы «и краткое» есть буква «И» с ударением. 
Для того чтобы убедится в правильности такого ударения в его имени, возьмите «Акафист святому великомученику и целителю ПантелеИмону» на церковно-славянском языке.

Comment: Наверно, все-таки не во-всех. 
Вы мой-то ответ прочитали?

А в греческом "буква И с ударением" вполне себе может читаться как неслоговое И. Там же дифтонг.

И вообще дело не в неправильном прочтении. Вы предлагаете прочесть тест на *церковно-славянском языке*. А мы говорим о русском. Заимствованное имя приспособилось под русскую фонетику. Вопрос в том, сохранять ли его якобы греческое звучание (на самом деле - именно церковнославянское) или употреблять руссифицированный варинт.

Имя приспособлено под русский, стало

Comment: В данном случае Вы говорите не о русифицированном варианте, а осовремененном. А точнее о новоязе в Церкви (т.е. новом языке, создаваемом бывшими неверующими). Благоговение должно быть и в Церкви и в быту. Ваш ответ, что в быту возможно и иное произношение имени святого, абсолютно не допустим!
Святой великомучениче и целителю ПантелеИмоне, моли Бога о нас грешных! 
С началом Великого Поста! 
Давайте не будем прививать нашему народу новые звучания и произношения. Наши православные предки передали нам необыкновенное сокровище церковно-славянский язык. Наша обязанность - беречь наследство.

Comment: >В данном случае Вы говорите не о русифицированном варианте, а осовремененном. 

С чего Вы взяли? И кто Вам дал право решать за меня, о чем я говорю?
Я говорю ровно то, что написано. А написано "русифицированный". С ошибкой, правда, но это у меня бывает, прошу простить. 

Я одного не могу понять, Вы серьезно полагаете, что прослушивание церковно-славянский варианта произношения что-то даст в понимании языка русского? Простите, а Вы вообще знаете ЦСЯ? И на каком уровне?

Comment: >С началом Великого Поста!   
  
И Вам того же. 

>Давайте не будем прививать нашему народу новые звучания и произношения.  
  
Нашему - это церковно-славянскому? Я что-то не слышал о таком народе.

Comment: Вы прекрасно поняли - православному народу.
ЦС языком владею на уровне церковного богослужения, свободно читаю и пишу тексты. 
Вот только не понятно, как возможно использовать вне церковного употребления имени святого Православной Церкви? В домашней молитве? Но домашняя молитвы это часть духовной жизни православного христианина!
Я верующий человек и серьезно полагаю, что чтение и прослушивание текстов на ЦС языке дает душе человека познание БОГА. Ибо ЦС язык это язык БОГООБЩЕНИЯ! К сожалению, часть людей этого не осознает.
И давайте будем корректны, тем более, что сейчас время Великого Поста.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно ПантелеймОн.

Answer (score 0):

До крещения имя у Святого Великомученника было ПантолЕон (в дословном переводе с греческого как "Везде лев". Панто - "везде", лЕон - "лев", или "в любой ситуации мужественен как лев"). По гречески Παντολέων звучит так: http://translate.google.ru/?hl=ru&tab=TT#el/ru/%CE%A0%CE%B1%CE%BD%CF%84%CE%BF%CE%BB%CE%AD%CF%89%CE%BD%20 . Во многих европейских языках в слове "лЕон" ударение ставиться на гласный звук "Е".

Однажды, возвращаясь от учителя-лекаря, юноша увидел лежавшего на дороге мертвого ребенка, укушенного ядовитой змеёй, которая извивалась тут же рядом. Исполнившись сострадания и жалости, ПантолЕон стал просить Господа о воскрешении умершего и умерщвлении ядовитого гада. Он твердо решил, что в случае исполнения его молитвы станет христианином и примет святое Крещение. И по действию Божественной благодати ребенок ожил, а змея разлетелась на куски на глазах удивленного ПантолЕона. Святой Ермолай крестил юношу и дал имя ему ПантелЕймон "Всемилостивый". По гречески Παντελεήμων звучит так: http://translate.google.ru/?hl=ru&tab=TT#el/ru/%CE%A0%CE%B1%CE%BD%CF%84%CE%B5%CE%BB%CE%B5%CE%AE%CE%BC%CE%BF%CE%BD .

Справка: ПантелЕймон († 305 год) — христианский святой, почитаемый в лике великомучеников, целитель, врач безмездный (бесплатно лечащий). Память совершается в Православной церкви 9 августа (27 июля по юлианскому календарю т.е. по старому стилю), в Католической церкви — 27 июля.

Comment: Не стоит, имхо, доверять гуглу прочтение имен собственных. 
Но не в этом дело. Вы так и не дали прямого ответа, как правильно произносить имя по-русски.